# How to implement Barcode scanner in react js website

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone tell me how to integrate a barcode scanner with react js website.when I click scan button it must scan the barcode using camera and display the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-qr-barcode-scanner][1]

To quote their usage

```js
import React from "react";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-qr-barcode-scanner";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("Not Found");

  return (
    <>
      <BarcodeScannerComponent
        width={500}
        height={500}
        onUpdate={(err, result) => {
          if (result) setData(result.text);
          else setData("Not Found");
        }}
      />
      <p>{data}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If it scans a qr code, the data can be accessed with result.text in the supplied function to onUpdate
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-barcode-scanner

Comment: This solution no longer works with React 17, cloned and patched version of this package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner?activeTab=versions

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer This doen't work with latest React version

 `npm i @steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner
unable to resolve dependency tree
Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner@1.1.2
 node_modules/@steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner
 ERR!   @steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner@"*" from the root project    
ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Can you provide a demo repo? I have this running in production.